Bounded Metric Spaces - Equivalent Statements
I came across an exercise related to bounded metric spaces that I couldn't quite understand.
Def: A subset $S$ of a metric space $X$ is said to be bounded if there exists an $M>0$ such that for all $x,y\in S,d(x,y)\leq M$
The exercise is as follows: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $S$ be a nonempty subset of X. Show that the following three statements are equivalent:

$\exists M>0$ such that $\forall x, y \in S, d(x,y) \leq M$
$\exists R>0$ and a $z_0 \in X$ such that $\forall x \in S, d(x,z_0) \leq R$
$\forall z \in X, \exists R_z > 0$ such that $\forall x \in S, d(x, z) \leq R_z$

The proof works by showing $1 \Rightarrow 2 \Rightarrow 3 \Rightarrow 1$.
I get how my professor goes from 1 to 2, and from 3 to 1, but I'm caught up on 2 to 3.
My professor has: Suppose 2 holds. Let $z \in X$ and set $R_z = R + d(z,z_0)$. Then, we have $\forall x \in S$, $d(x,z) \leq d(x,z_0) + d(z_0,z) \leq R + d(z_0,z) = R_z$. So 3 holds.
I don't see how we are allowed to assume that $d(z,z_0)$ is finite. How can we extend 2, where we say that a $z$ exists, to suddenly all $z \in X$? How are we allowed to bound the distance between the $z$'s? Thanks.

$\forall z\in X$, $d(z,z_0)$ is finite by definition of a metric.

As Anne Bauval said, $d$ is a map from $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq0}$ (and infinity is not a real number)

Just for curiosity, where is this definition of bounded subset from?  Thanks for any clarification.

My professor states that definition in his lecture notes. However statement (2) is from Baby Rudin 2.18i. Just depends whether we can prove equivalence.

Thanks for clarifying.  I was reviewing Rudin Def. 2.18(i) and it appears slightly different, in that the metric $d\left(x,z_{0}\right) \lt R$ (using your notation) as opposed to $\le R$, but this distinction may not be critical here.  Thanks again.

First, we don't need to assume that $d(z,z_0)$ is finite. That follows directly from the definition of a metric. Remember a metric is a function $d:X\to[0,+\infty)$ so it can only be finite.
Secondly in the assumption 2) we say a $z_0\in X$ exists so that the distance between every element $x\in S$ in $S$ and $z_0$ is less than or equal to $R>0$. Now also every element in $X$ has a finite distance to $z_0$ and we can add those two distance, which are still finite.

If a distance is always finite, how does that not imply that every subset is bounded? I.e. the distance between two points x and y will always be bounded no matter what. Because surely I could assign a finite distance between any two points, and thus an M satisfying that condition. How do we know that every element in X has a finite distance to $z_0$?

Not really. Your definition (which is the standard definition) of a bounded set doesn't say the the difference of any two elements in the set must be finite. It says that it must be smaller than a given distance $M>0$.

For example: the set $(0,1)\in\Bbb{R}$ is bounded, since $d(x,y) \leq 1$ for any two points $x,y\in (0,1)$. So $M=1$ in our definition. But the $\Bbb{R}$ itself is not bounded, since we can find two points on the real number that are further apart than a fixed number $M>0$.

Even more concretely: let's for example say $\Bbb{R}$ is bounded and the bound is $M=100$. But then $d(101,0) = | 101 -0 | = 101 > M$ which is a contradiction. This contradiction we can find for every arbitrary $M$, so $\Bbb{R}$ is not bounded. Note that still the distance between the two numbers is finite, but it's bigger than what we want.

Ah so the result follows from the fact that we have to choose the M first (because it comes first in the definition)? After choosing an M, all points have to be within the distance. That’s contrary to choosing a couple of points, and then choosing a distance that contains them.

Yes! Exactly. The order of quantifiers is extremely important here.
